# How to add print functionality inside office add-ins

Tags: office-js

In our organisation we had built an Office Add-in. Now we wanted to add print functionality in our add-in. Can anybody help me how to add print functionality using Office javascript API.

Comment: No print API yet. Please add your request for new API in [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). Mention which Apps you need this in (Excel, Word, PowerPoint)

Answer (score 2):

There is no print API in the Office.JS library. You can get the file as a blob of various formats with the [getFileAsyc API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync). I'll ask the product team if they know how that blob can be printed and update this answer if I find out anything.

**UPDATE:** You cannot send the document to a locally installed printer or to a shared printer on the user's LAN from within the Office Add-in. You **can** send the blob to an online printing service, such as FedEx, or a custom service created on the user's corp network.

Comment: Is this still the case that printing is still not feasible through office.js?

Comment: The answer is still accurate.

Comment: Is a print event added to the Excel Office JS APIs?